# Remove default HTTP Headers from HTTPie's request

Tags: python, httpie

There are a couple of [default headers that HTTPie sets](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#http-headers). I'm wondering if there is a way to remove some header, like `Accept-Encoding`?

The reason I like to unset `Accept-Encoding` is to check our server's behavior about HTTP Compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Headers follow by a colon.

- No headers:

```
http -v https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 \
     Accept: \
     Accept-Encoding: \
     Connection: \
     Host: \
     User-Agent:
```

Request:

```
GET /todos/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

- Standard:

```
http -v https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
```

Request:

```
GET /todos/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.8
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

The `-v` option display the request. Also, remember no spaces after `\` in multiline bash commands.

Answer (score 3):

Per https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#http-headers , you can **override** those headers.  For example, set `Accept-Encoding` to empty to achieve the same effect as if you had removed it -- per the rules at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3 .

Comment: Setting `Accept-Encoding` to empty results in two lines of `Accept-Encoding`. I am not sure if HTTP servers can handle this correctly.